# How authenticate a local player with swift?

Tags: iphone, authentication, swift, ios8, game-center

I'm trying to integrate game center to my game and create a leaderboard.

I already create the leaderboard on iTunes Connect, enable the game center and create a sandbox tester.

Despite all I have this error :

`not able to authenticate fail 
error is nil`

This is my error println (see my code)

Did I miss something ?

Here the code of my gameViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import iAd
import GameKit

var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
var highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")


class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {


var adBannerView: ADBannerView!

var leaderboardIdentifier: String? = nil
var gameCenterEnabled: Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var skView = self.originalContentView as SKView
    var scene:SKScene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

    skView.presentScene(scene)

    loadAds()


}

func authenticateLocalPlayer()
{
    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler =
        { (viewController : UIViewController!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if viewController != nil
            {
                self.presentViewController(viewController, animated:true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                if localPlayer.authenticated
                {
                    self.gameCenterEnabled = true
                    localPlayer.loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler
                        { (leaderboardIdentifier, error) -> Void in
                            if error != nil
                            {
                                print("error")
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                self.leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier
                                println("\(self.leaderboardIdentifier)") //in your example "VHS" should be returned
                            }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    println("not able to authenticate fail")
                    self.gameCenterEnabled = false

                    if (error != nil)
                    {
                        println("\(error.description)")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        println(    "error is nil")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you enable Game Center for the app on iTunes Connect and subsequently edited the project to use the same bundle ID (or something like that)? You should check the Game Center programming guide for more info. This really sounds like a simple setup step (either in iTunes Connect or the app's Info.plist) is missing here.

Comment: Thank you. Effectively the bundle ID wasn't the same... however it can't log. The debug area display "not able to authenticate fail" and "error is nil" so my println.

Comment: I edited the question with the new error... I can't set up the game center it makes me crasy !!! :x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve by myself.

code this :     `var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()`

instead of : `var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()`